# Contact form 7 select field value after post request

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to get form dropdown field value. All other type of fields value can get but only select field value create problem.
This is in my form, one is text and other is select

```
<div class="col-lg-6 first"><label>Full Name
[text* FullName id:fullname]</label></div>
<div class="col-lg-6 last"><label>Business Type
[select* primarybusiness id:primarybusiness include_blank "Manufacturer" "Brand" "Retailer" "Wholesaler"]</label></div>
```

This is what I am trying to get

```
$mydb = new wpdb('user','password','database','localhost');
    $form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( $form_to_DB ) 
        $formData = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();        
    $fullname = $formData['FullName'];
    $primarybusiness = $formData['primarybusiness'];
```

when i store it in database only $fullname enter but $primarybusiness give nothing.
This is what i used to save.

```
$mydb->insert( 'mytable', array( 'fullname'=>$fullname,'primarybusiness'=>$primarybusiness), array( '%s' ) );
```

Comment: Add `var_dump( $formData );` somewhere and see if `primarybusiness` actually exists and is not empty. Also, why do you instantiate a new instance of the `wpdb` class? Why not use the global `$wpdb` variable?

Comment: Thanks for reply, But not found space to var_dump. But it's work for me by changing it by $b = $formData['primarybusiness']; and then $primarybusiness =$b[0];

Comment: Try `$primarybusiness = $formData['primarybusiness'][0]`;

Comment: I tried it. but it's not working, I don't know why it's not working. that's way i just store it in one variable and then get value of index 0 to save it.

Comment: are you hooking `wpcf7_before_send_mail` ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  There's no simple solution for getting the pipes, it's kind of a pain.  The pipes are stored as a class, and you can push to array where `pipe[0]` is the value, and `pipe[1]` is the option description.

```php
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'cf7_pipes_so_67686211');
function cf7_pipes_so_67686211( $contact_form ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $mydb = new wpdb('user','password','database','localhost');
    
    // Get Form Tags
    $tags = $contact_form->scan_form_tags();
    $pipe_array = array();
    // Find the Values of the Pipes
    foreach ($tags as $tag){
        if ($tag->name === 'primarybusiness'){
           $pipe_array = $tag->pipes->to_array();
        }
    }
    // Get the form data
    $form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( $form_to_DB ) {
        $formData = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();
        $fullname = $formData['FullName'];
        foreach ($pipe_array as $value) {
            // Compare and find the pipe value
            if ( $posted_data['primarybusiness'][0] === $value[1] ){
                $primarybusiness = $value[0];
            }
        }
        $mydb->insert( 'mytable', array( 'fullname'=>$fullname,'primarybusiness'=>$primarybusiness), array( '%s' ) );
    }
}
```